# Accessing a submethod of an argument of an overriden method in android?

Tags: java, android, overriding, downcast

This must be a noob question, but I can't find the proper wait to achieve the following:

In android, I made a subclass MyView extending a View class. In B, I've defined a method mMethod not present in the View class.

Now, I want to set an OnClickListener interface on MyView. Doing this, I must override a onClick method when defining a new OnClickListener. Furthermore, I would like to access the mMethod method in onClick, but the overriden method is expecting a View class instance, not a MyView's one. So what can I do ?

To be more precise:

```
public class MyView extends View{
  ...
    public void mMethod(){
    ...
    }
}
```

And in the main class (Activity)

```
MyView  myView = new MyView () 
//It's not the correct constructor, but it's not the point

myView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onClick(View v){
        //Here I would like to access mMethod of MyView
        ???
    }

}
```

Is using `myView.mMethod()` is the only solution ? Is it possible to downcast `v` to `(MyView)v` ? If so, how to do it ? Should I define a sub-interface ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
public boolean onClick(View v) {
    MyView mv = (MyView) v;
    mv.myMethod();
}
```

That way you know you're operating on the right view - and it will throw an exception if you are given the wrong kind of view. (If you don't want to throw an exception, you could use `instanceof` to test that it's the right kind of view first.)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was so quick that I can't check the accepted answer yet!